# The difference between cross domain and same domain requests

Tags: httprequest

I am in the process of learning angular and I am a little confused as to what the difference is between cross domain and same domain requests. How do you know which type of request you are making?

Comment: has nothing to to with angularjs. cross domain is when your script is loaded from domain A and is requesting a resource from domain B. the same domain request is obviously A instead of B.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs is a front end framework. You need a server component(rails, node.js etc) to handle requests from angularjs and handle the data(Users, post, comments etc). 
If you are developing an Angularjs application that sends a request to a server that is NOT located with in the same domain/website, then it is a cross domain request. If you are developing an Angularjs application using a server that is contained with in the same domain/website, then it is a same domain request. If you want to develop an Angualrjs application using cross domain requests, you need to learn Cross-origin resource sharing(CORS) which defines how the server handles request from another domain/website.