# Not able to send a DELETE request with fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When I send a delete request to a certain endpoint, for example with [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) from terminal like

`http delete http://localhost:8181/admin/applications/uspecs`

I get a valid behavior, as in `{ success: true }` as response body.
But when I do

```
fetch (
  'http://localhost:8181/admin/applications/uspecs',
  { method: 'DELETE' }
)
.then(res => doSomethingWithResponse())
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

In javascript code, then I get a

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8181/admin/applications/uspecs.
Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

error on the console. What am I missing? I am getting a valid methods list on options request.

Comment: Read about cross-origin resource sharing  (CORS) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors.

Comment: In the OPTIONS response, I am getting `allow: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST` list. That should do it, no? @OndrejSvejdar

Comment: Can you use fiddler composer to send OPTIONS request to the endpoint and post the response you're getting. Also the post is confusing - make sure the OPTIONS and DELETE request are send to the same endpoint (in your post those are different).

Comment: updated. @OndrejSvejdar

Comment: I don't see any OPTIONS response in your post. please post the full response headers to that request.

Comment: When you do a http request from a browser, it automatically sends the OPTIONS request. Here's what it looks like: http://imgur.com/YQ0jVQR

Comment: @ThiefMaster http://imgur.com/YQ0jVQR

Comment: Assuming you have a node/express backend, you need to add this in a middleware to allow CORS:

    `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'domainToAllow.com:port');`
    `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');`
    `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header containing the allowed methods. Currently your header is named `methods`.

Comment: How should i add that header?

Comment: That depends on your server-side framework. Check its documentation.