# load div from another page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

i would like to load a div from a page in my page with jquery

Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/y5pfm4ay/) but it doesn't work, what is wrong in my code ?

In my example I'm using

```
$('.namebook1origin').load($('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook1'));
```

but in my page I'm using

```
$('.namebook1origin').load($('update.html #namebook1'));
```

Here is a live example

```js
$('.namebook1origin').load($('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook1'));
$('.namebook2origin').load($('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook2'));
$('.namebook3origin').load($('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook3'));
$('.namebook4origin').load($('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook4'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="namebook1origin">.</span><br/>
    
<span class="namebook2origin">.</span><br/>
    
<span class="namebook3origin">.</span><br/> 
    
<span class="namebook4origin">.</span><br/>
```

Comment: Is `www.booclin.ovh` your website? If not you will get CORS issue, Additionally you need to pass URL to `load` method `$('.namebook4origin').load('https://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook4')`

Comment: Don't wrap your URL and selector in `$()`.

Comment: yes in my example i added the full link but i use this one in my page load($('update.html #namebook1'));

Answer (score 2):

[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accepts a string as input not a jquery object, unram the `$()` from the string

```js
$('.namebook1origin').load('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook1');
$('.namebook2origin').load('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook2');
$('.namebook3origin').load('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook3');
$('.namebook4origin').load('http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook4');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="namebook1origin">.</span><br/>
    
<span class="namebook2origin">.</span><br/>
    
<span class="namebook3origin">.</span><br/> 
    
<span class="namebook4origin">.</span><br/>
```

The snippet doesn't work because of [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Comment: I have <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> but it doesn't work yet, and in your example too ?

Comment: he wants you to explain that you may not use `.load($(url))` but `.load(url)`

Comment: ah sorry ok about .load(url) instead of .load($(url)) ... why I don't have access? all my pages are in www.booclin.ovh, i want to load a div from a page in another who are both uploaded in www.booclin.ovh

Comment: @clodo0683 if you are on the same domain the cors should not be a problem, check your console for any errors

Comment: there is any errors in my consol that's why i don't really understand ? May be I should add all my js in my example (not so much code)

Comment: check the network tab for the xhr requests, see the the xhr request has the body with the content of your update page

Comment: can you provide the link where you use this script?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) should be like this: `$(selector).load("internalDomainURL #div",callback);`

`$("#namebook1origin").load("http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/last/update.html #namebook1");`