# Connect Ionic with ERP odoo

Tags: angular, http, ionic3, json-rpc, odoo-11

I am working with Ionic 3 app. Backend for my app is [Odoo v11](https://www.odoo.com/).
When connecting my mobile app with [Odoo v11](https://www.odoo.com/) using [angular4-odoo-jsonrpc](https://libraries.io/npm/angular4-odoo-jsonrpc) I have to face below error.

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/session/authenticate: Response to the preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

this is my Code:

```js
import { OdooJsOnProvider } from '../../providers/odoo-js-on/odoo-js-on';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, IonicPage, Loading, LoadingController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UtilsProvider } from "../../providers/utils/utils";
import * as Ng6OdooRPCService from 'angular6-odoo-jsonrpc';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular4-odoo-jsonrpc'


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private odooRPC: OdooRPCService
  ) {
    this.odooRPC.init({
      odoo_server: "http://127.0.0.1:8069",
      http_auth: "admin:admin" // optional
    });
    this.odooRPC.login('odoo', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
      console.log('login success');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('login failed', err);
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches.

Allow your localhost and port (8100) access by managing CORS on your backend

OR

Set-up proxying https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: how i can Allow my localhost and port (8100) access by managing CORS on your backend

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage `CORS` from your backend.
Read more about `CORS` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845455/8850397).

If you want to test your mobile app avoiding `CORS` add this [Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to `Google Chrome`. But use this type of Extensions only for testing.

Comment: i stop the CORS from Browser using this command google-chrome --disable-web-security but still same error

Answer (score 0):

allow CORS in your backend like this :

```
@http.route('/route/<id>', type='http', cors='*', csrf=False, auth="user")
def method(self, id, **kwargs):
```

cors='*'