# CORS policy is blocked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I create simple google chrome extension and I get JSON data but this error is generated

`dashboard.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://humane-like-developer-edition.ap4.force.com/services/apexrest/SessionHuman' from origin 'chrome-extension://dgbedclgdamcknolmpacbbigocadoiko' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This is my code

```
var HttpClient=function()
{
    this.get=function(aUrl,aCallback)
    {
        var anHttpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(anHttpRequest.readyState==4 && anHttpRequest.status==200)
            {
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
        anHttpRequest.open("GET",aUrl,true);
        anHttpRequest.send(null);
    }
}
var theurl='https://humane-like-developer-edition.ap4.force.com/services/apexrest/SessionHuman';
var client=new HttpClient();
client.get(theurl,function(response){
alert(response);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Answer (score 0):

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

The requested resource must respond an `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` header matching your `Origin` request header.

If it is a public API you should respond with `*`.
Note: Protocol is type of the response if it is not `*`, multiple values are **not allowed**, as well as wildcards are not allowed.

Comment: How to pass header in javascript

Comment: It's a **RESPONSE** header.

Comment: please give a simple example

Comment: Please google for the difference of the words `request` and `response`.

Comment: give a syntax of this

Comment: Syntax and valid value: `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin: *`