# Should I be concerned by "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property on cross-origin object" logs

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain

Following errors were logged on my website, should I be concerned or can I just ignore them?

```
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "dispatchEvent" on cross-origin object - url: moz-extension://f985b107-bcb9-45d4-95c4-b1bb39443725/js/inject.js - line: 65 - column: 0 - error: SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "dispatchEvent" on cross-origin object (browser: Firefox 55)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors

( I'm out of flags )

Comment: Read the error message more carefully. They aren't on your website. `url: moz-extension://f985b107-bcb9-45d4-95c4-b1bb39443725/js/inject.js`. They are coming from a browser extension. We have no idea if you should be concerned or not, we don't know what extensions you have installed or how trustworthy they are (and this isn't a programming problem unless you are writing the extension yourself).

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing from an unknown user's firefox extension. Doesn't reproduce for me locally. I would love to know if anyone figures out what the extension is.

Comment: anytime you see "SecurityError" you should be concerned - something is trying to do something it probably shouldn't be.  if after you have investigated and can discount it because of - as suggested - unknown extensions, and that it is harmless, then you can sleep peacefully

Answer (score 3):

You should not be concerned, you can ignore them.

It comes from extension of a firefox browser: `url: moz-extension://f985b107-bcb9-45d4-95c4-b1bb39443725/js/inject.js`
who's trying to attach event but CrossOrigin query is not allowed.

Good documentation explaining CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS