# React native fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a problem with fetch data. My friend creates Rest Api.
There is my fun:

```
const AnyCors = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
const urlAllBus = `http://207.185.72.111:15430/stops?size=15`;
    fetchBusStop = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
    fetch(AnyCors+urlAllBus)
      .then((result) => {
        if (!result.ok) throw result.json();
        return result.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        error.then((body) => {
          console.log('Bad', body);
          rejects(body);
        }),
      );
  });
};
```

I create an app with react-native. When I use only urlAllBus my virtual machine work fine. The problem is with a physical machine. When I try using my fun with urlAllbus in chrome I get a problem with CORS so I used AnyCors+urlAllBus and everything works fine. But in the virtual and physical machine there solutions not work. I don't know what I should do

Comment: The problem should be solved on the server program. Not on the client.

Comment: Any idea what may be a problem on the server program ?

Comment: Your server should accept cors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors

Answer (score 0):

You friend's API should accept CORS by adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to its responses to allow any website to access it. They can also limit access to a specific site by setting the header to the base URL of such site, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`.

If the API is express-based, I hightly recommend the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package for the job, as it makes it a single-line change.

Otherwise, tell them to give [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) a read for more information about CORS :)