# How to get the same predictive search data that shows under the google search bar

Tags: javascript, search, searchbar, google-search-api

I'm trying to find a way to get the same predictive search results that shows under the Google search bar as your typing. I'm not talking about custom search for a specific site either. I thought this wasn't possible until I came across a new tab page extension from the chrome store.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/start-a-better-new-tab/kgifkabikplflflabkllnpidlbjjpgbp?hl=en

Their search bar predictions matches Google's exactly. What source are they getting that data from? Are there any other predictive search services/APIs that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### *"What source are they getting that data from?"*

By looking at the extension's source code, this URL:
https://google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=en&q=foo

It's the same API that Google uses on its search page. But that API is protected by [CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845455/1913729), so it can't be accessed from any webpage. A browser extension can, because it's granted more rights. To use it, you would need a proxy server (either your own, or a free one, such as the one in the example below).

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search'),
  suggestionsList = document.getElementById('suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', autocomplete);
autocomplete();

function autocomplete() {
  const q = searchInput.value;
  const proxy = 'https://cors-everywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  
  fetch(`${proxy}https://google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=en&q=${q}`, {
    headers: { origin: 'google.com' }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    suggestionsList.innerHTML = res[1].map(x => `<li>${x}</li>`).join('')
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="search" value="foo" />
<ul id="suggestions"></ul>
```

### *"Are there any other ... services/APIs?"*

We can't answer that here, as it's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This type of questions tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, works perfect for my situation. Are there any legal issues on using the API on a webpage?

Comment: Google certainly does not want you to use it. As for the legality, I can't say for sure, but I would not use it outside of a personal, hobby site