# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ajax

I have next ajax request usnig jquery in my react app, here is this request:

**index.js**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : 'http://localhost/my-app/server/send.php',
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
  }
}, function(data) {
  alert(data, "success!")
})
```

**send.php**

```
<?
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "...response...";
```

But my ajax call raises an error in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/my-app/server/send.php' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass 
 access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

But I send headers, what is wrong?

Comment: Your problem is related to CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). Take a look here [Understanding CORS (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)

Comment: @DDomen it does not help

Comment: Can you check if the url you are calling in your preflight is actually the same? (Use network tab in dev tools)

Comment: Your server needs to allow all origins, or explicitly accept `localhost:3000` as an origin.

Comment: @James See my code in the question - there is `*` means all allowed and it does not work, that's why I ask :)

Comment: IMHO, @James wanted to mention that you will need to configure your server, to accept requests from the origin localhost:3000. The code you shared is from the client side.