# Why fetch() request fails in chrome console when URL is empty ? . But Works fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

**When I try to do this on chrome browser:**

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(user=> console.log(user))
```

it seems net::ERR_FAILED[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Comment: Great !!! Thankyou @sergiu paraschiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Sergiu Paraschiv noted in the comments, the core issue is CORS, and I highly recommend reading the link he provided.

However, just to elaborate slightly, for your specific case, of trying to make an AJAX request on the "start" or "no URL" page of a  browser ...

... different browsers handle such "home page AJAX requests" differently, because such a page doesn't have a true URL.

Chrome (evidently) treats it as a URL of "", and so *any* URL would by definition violate CORS.  In contrast, Firefox seems to ignore the CORS URL restrictions on requests made from the "home page".

More generally, if you're going to be testing your API without a client, I'd highly recommend using an independent request-making tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), as such tools will completely bypass CORS restrictions (and also let you make POST, DELETE, and other non-GET requests).