# $.getJSON doesn't return properly ([object Object], undefined or nothing)

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, ajax

So basically I'm having the standerd issue of the ajax call not retrieving the JSON data. It would be that it was an array, and your not using the index. But I *AM* using an index on the front-end. All the questions I've seen for this haven't worked, (most of them being "use a index") and I've looked at the documentation. I've tried aiming directly at the database but I'm currently using a php file. I've tried the standard way of using $.getJSON (which retuns nothing) so I tryed defining it as a variable and that returns [object Object] or undefined (I still have both in my code). Now, for some code
database.json

```
[{"Usrname":"Admin","Comment":"Comments Are Working!"},{"Usrname":"billy","Comment":"y u no work"},{"Usrname":"jrnvreifnwrg","Comment":"vfrjinoiewg"},{"Usrname":"bill","Comment":"testing 123 testing"},{"Usrname":"James","Comment":"Now all that has to be done it to show the text in a chat box"},{"Usrname":"test","Comment":"hi there pls work"},{"Usrname":"Benjamin","Comment":"Hello"},{"Usrname":"Benjamin","Comment":"Hello"},{"Usrname":"Bill","Comment":"Hello"}]
```

- I've tried with and without the quotes around the whole thing, didn't seem to change anything

get.php

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = file_get_contents('database.json');
echo $data;
?>
```

contact.html
(just a snippet, the comment div is there and functioning)

```html
<script>

      $(document).ready(function () {
        response = $.getJSON('https://ambitioussociableprotools.babyboy666.repl.co/get.php')  
        document.getElementById("comments").innerText += response
        document.getElementById("comments").innerText += response[0]
       
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      $.getJSON("https://ambitioussociableprotools.babyboy666.repl.co/get.php", function(data){
        document.getElementById("comments").innerText += data[0].Usrname
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      data = $.get("https://ambitioussociableprotools.babyboy666.repl.co/get.php")
      document.getElementById("comments").innerText += data
      document.getElementById("comments").innerText += data[0].Usrname
      var obj = JSON.parse(data)
      document.getElementById("comments").innerText += obj
      document.getElementById("comments").innerText += obj[0]
      document.getElementById("comments").innerText += obj[0].Usrname
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is CORS, take a look at: [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Change your PHP endpoint to:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = file_get_contents('database.json');
echo $data;
?>
```

If you want to control access from a specific origin, you can change `*` to your request origin. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: once again, this didn't seem to change anything when I added it, I'm considering rewriting it using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It seems to be working now. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3cbyo17/

Comment: well it may need a little messing around with but this prob fixed the main issue, so ill accept

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` doesn't return the object. It's an asynchronous function, so you use a callback function, which receives the object as the parameter.

```
$.get("https://ambitioussociableprotools.babyboy666.repl.co/get.php", function(data) {
  document.getElementById("comments").innerText += data[0].Usrname;
})
```

Comment: attempted this, and it didn't return anything whatsoever.(is there possibly another issue?)

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Use the Network tab to see what's actually being returned by the AJAX call.

Comment: Try just putting `console.log(data);` in the function.

Comment: I am currently on a device without devtools, (cellphone[or if there is i don't want to try and use it with a touch screen]) ill get back to you later