# Web socket CORS issue in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was working on implementing web sockets in springboot, I followed the example spring has given in there docs. But I am getting cors error while trying to connect to socket from Js frontend.

Controller-

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/Hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public  Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message){
        return new Greeting("Hello, "+ HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()));
    }
}
```

Model classes-

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HelloMessage {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Greeting {
    private String message;
}
```

configuration class-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topics");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
```

Frontend-

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080//stomp-endpoint');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080//topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
        });
    });
}
```

backend and frontend are working on different port numbers. While making the connect req I am getting this error - `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080//stomp-endpoint/info?t=1630575287138' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How can I resolve this issue !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors

Answer (score 0):

You can add the source origin to the `@CrossOrigin` annotation.

`@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost"})`

See also [Rest Service Cors](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)