# can an attacker call function from another website?

Tags: javascript, security, web, xss, csrf

The website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
                <script>
                        function e(q){eval(q)}
                </script>
</html>
```

If i go to the website and write `javascript:e("alert()")` function e will be executed but stuff like `http://website.com/javascript:e("alert()")` will not work i ther a way to execute the function e from another website?

Comment: You have to load the website for the JS on it to load. But it might be put in an iframe or something. It would help if you clarify why you want this information.

Comment: The JavaScript execution on Websites is protected on several levels. Injecting code isn't that easy (anymore). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors) may help you.

Comment: Also very relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy