# Do CORS errors prevent a request from being sent?

Tags: javascript

I'm sending an `XMLHttpRequest` to a tracking pixel whenever my page loads.

It's getting a `200` response code, but I can see where the status shows `CORS error` in Developer Tools.

Is my request still being sent, but I'm just not able to see the response due to the CORS errors?

Since it's just a tracking pixel and not an API, I don't need to get the response, just need to make sure that URL is being hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) are always sent, but access to details of the response may be blocked by the Same Origin Policy if permission isn't granted by the server using CORS.

[Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) such as those including cookies or changes (outside a limited safe set) to HTTP request headers will trigger a preflight OPTIONS request. The request JavaScript wants to send will not be sent unless the response to the preflight is used to grant permission.