# How to get 404 status code from fetch in react

Tags: reactjs

I am tryibg to get the status code of a url.

fetch(`https/**********************`).then((response) => {
console.log(response.status,"STATUS"); // returns 200
});

200 status code is coming. But 404 status code is not coming.

Instead of that CORS error is coming.

How to get 404 status code?

Comment: You are getting code 200 beacue the request was success. You only will get 404 when the resource is found.

Comment: but in networks tab , its showing 404 but in console its showing Cross origin error

Comment: To avoid CORS during local development i use a extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en) More info about CORS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors