# Sending requests to discord's /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id} not working

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm sending a request to discord's /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id} endpoint,

```
fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/*REDACTED*/members/*REDACTED*`, {
    method: 'patch', 
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bot ${oAuth.token}`
    },
    body: {
        'nick': 'test'
    }
}).then((response)=> response.json()).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

But it keeps logging this error in the console:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://discord.com/api/guilds/*REDACTED*/members/*REDACTED*'
> from origin '************' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I don't seem to understand why it's not working :/

This is done with pure js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors)

Comment: Have you tried googling before asking a question?

Comment: yeah i still don't really understand

Comment: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2545

Comment: You can't access discord api from the browser. End of story