# Python requests POST request - cannot make it right

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a correct request to the server using python requests.

There is a powershell reference that works perfectly and returns data:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 YaBrowser/24.1.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://url/api/auth" `
-Method "POST" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="ru,en;q=0.9"
  "Cache-Control"="max-age=0"
  "Origin"="url"
  "Referer"="url"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-origin"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Not_A Brand`";v=`"8`", `"Chromium`";v=`"120`", `"YaBrowser`";v=`"24.1`", `"Yowser`";v=`"2.5`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
} `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("{`"rememberMe`":false,`"version`":{`"date`":`"2024-02-09T17:00:00.000Z`",`"company`":`"$([char]1054)$([char]1054)$([char]1054) \`"$([char]1090)\`"`",`"number`":`"8.8.1`"},`"eng`":false,`"username`":`"xxx`",`"password`":`"xxx`"}"))
```

I try to replicate this request using the following script:

```
post_login_url = 'url'
    auth_values = {
        "rememberMe": "false",
        "version": {
            "date": "2024-02-09T10:00:00.000Z",
            "company": "ООО \"А\"",
            "number": "8.8.1"},
        "eng": 'false',
        "username": ab_username,
        "password": ab_password}
    
    headerscont = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 YaBrowser/24.1.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "ru,en;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\", \"YaBrowser\";v=\"24.1\", \"Yowser\";v=\"2.5\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "Referer": "url",
        "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        }
with HTMLSession() as session:
        post = session.post(post_login_url, headers=headerscont, data=auth_values)
```

But it keeps return response 400 "unexpected token r in JSON at position 0"
Whats wrong with the request made via script?

I tried different formatting of Auth_values (tried to pass them as a string), also tried to encode the body using utf-8 without success.

Comment: Try `json=auth_values` instead `data=auth_values`

Comment: Just tried. Looks like a progress as the error message has changed to 

'b'{"code":"CORS","message":"Not allowed by CORS"}'' with the same code 400

Comment: Then maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845203/understanding-cors

Comment: I digged into it earlier as I saw this error. As far as I understand the cors faq page via link sais that server is probably refusing request because the itis not being sent from the same domain. But, in this case request made via powershell would not have worked either. Yet it works. What powershell does that the script does not to obtain proper response?